# Get HSV values from the Digital Colour Meter in macOS

Tags: macos, applications, color, utilities

Just wondering if it was possible to get the HSV values when using macOS's default Digital Colour Meter.
Here is a view of the different options I get:

[image]

HSV doesn't seem available although it is a common colour space.

Comment: Strictly speaking, HSV is a colour **model**, whereas the choices in the DCM are colour **spaces**, all based on the RGB model. RGB is a cubic model & HSV is cylindrical. I can only guess that the DCM is not designed to re-map these models.

Comment: While you can sometimes get more options by holding Alt while clicking on a drop-down list, that doesn't improve things here. If they haven't thought to include it in the app, then it's not there.